# custom nivo slider slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I want to customize the nivo slider slideshow with bullets appear in the inner image.

The Slideshow from Nivo Slider looks like this:
http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/

I want to customize the bullets like this:
http://wowslider.com/automatic-jquery-slider-noir-squares-demo.html
But the bullets appear in the right corner of image. How can do this?
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding the following to your CSS should do the trick:

```
.slider-wrapper{
position:relative;
}

.theme-default .nivo-controlNav{
position:absolute;
top:15px;
right:15px;
padding:0px;
z-index:9;
}
```

Comment: thx it works but i want to show bullet in a right corner bottom of image..help me

Comment: Changing 'top:15px;' to 'bottom:15px;' will move the bullets to the bottom right corner